# How to import webp image in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, webp

**I have searched the answer, but couldn't find any**

When importing an image in *.webp in typescript there is a need for declaration file, e.g. **declaration.d.ts**

In there must be provided something similar to follow up code:

```
declare module "*.webp" {
    const value: any;
    export = value;
}
```

After it, the import method is

```
import * as img from "path/to/image/img.webp"

<img src={img} alt="404" />
```

However, after the render no image will show up, because what is essentially exported is not an image itself but an [object Module]. Which can be easily seen with this

```
console.log(img)
```

In that img module is the path to put in, so the following can be used:

```
<img src={img.default} alt="404"/>
```

But I'm pretty certain,
A) I am declaring in a very wrong way, i.e. there must be a better export in declaration or better type to be written against **value**
B) I am using import in a wrong way.

So I am open for the better ways to deal with WebP import in React TS.
Help from you or links to rtfm will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using a front end build system (i.e. Webpack, Rollup, Grunt, Gulp)?

Comment: The declaration is just to make TypeScript happy, the actual support depends on your build tooling. Is it create-react-app or any kind of template?

Comment: It is create-react-app

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript gives an error if you try to import **webp** image as **ReactComponent**. So you should not import it as a component, but use only the **source** of image. Check this example:

```
import img from "./images/image.webp";
```

Now you can use this src in any of your tag like this.

```
<img src={img} />
```

Comment: It wont work from the beginning, because the code will throw something similar to "Cannot find module '../images/image.webp' or its corresponding type declarations.ts"

Answer (score 1):

In fact you have to use

```
import img from "./images/image.webp";
```

and then

```
<img src={img.src} />
```

this way it works

Comment: not works in react 18.2

Answer (score 0):

How I setup my folder for images.

I create a root folder called images.tsx then create an image object which is made up of all files. This way I can just import the `Image` const and access multiple images within one component file

```
import PlaceHolder from '../images/placeholder.jpg';
import LogoLrgTag from '../images/new-logo-lrg-tag.svg';
import LogoLrg from '../images/new-logo-lrg.svg';
import LogoVTag from '../images/new-logo-v-tag.svg'
import LogoV from '../images/new-logo-v.svg';
import LandscapePH1 from '../placeholders/placeholder-landscape-1.png';
import LandscapePH2 from '../placeholders/placeholder-landscape-2.png';
import LandscapePH3 from '../placeholders/placeholder-landscape-3.png';
import SearchIcon from '../images/search-icon.webp';


const Image = {
  PlaceHolder,
  LogoLrgTag,
  LogoLrg,
  LogoVTag,
  LogoV,
  LandscapePH1,
  LandscapePH2,
  LandscapePH3,
  SearchIcon
}

export default Image;
```

then I can just call in my components:

```
 import Image from '../../../assets/images/Image'; //import object

 <Button
  variant='outlined'
  onClick={() => {
    alert('do the thing!')
  }}
 >
  <img src={Image.SearchIcon} alt='search-icon'/>
     Help
</Button>
```